# After searching on a name from db how I can get the searched name listed using python Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, list, search

I do search for user name from DB, now I want when I select any name and click on add button it shows in the list under the search box.

for search code in HTML

```
 <form id="location_form" class="form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                      <label id="name-label">User Name</label>
                      <div id="item">
                      <input type="text"    name="user"      id="user_id"  oninput="get_user()" />
                      <input type="hidden"  name="user_h_id" id="user_h_id" />
                      <input type="hidden"  name="h_id"      id="h_id"/>
                      <button type="button"  id="add_user" class="btn btn-secondary"> Add User</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

in view.py

```
def get_location_details(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search_string = request.GET.get('q')
        charge_to_list = search_string.split(' ')
        q = (Q(username__icontains=charge_to_list[0]) | Q(fullname__icontains=charge_to_list[0]))
        for term in charge_to_list[1:]:
            if term != '':
                q.add((Q(username__icontains=term) | Q(fullname__icontains=term)), Q.AND)
        data_list = []
        qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(q, )[:10]
        for i in qs:
            data_dict = {}
            data_dict['id'] = i.id
            data_dict['username'] = i.username
            data_dict['fullname'] = i.fullname
            data_dict['show_label'] = str(i.username)
            data_list.append(data_dict)

        return JsonResponse(data_list, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new div using condition on data_list. And iterate over that data_list if it has values.
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) is the django docs for it

Comment: do I have to write something in view.py?

Comment: No, as you've data_list. Use that in the template